# concatenate two file globbings in bash

Tags: bash, glob

I have the below bash stript to print out `project.json` file paths:

```
projectDirectories=./src/*/
projectJsonFiles=${projectDirectories%%/}/project.json
for projectFilePath in $projectJsonFiles; do echo $projectFilePath; done
```

which gives me this output:

```
./src/foo-aspnet-configuration/project.json
./src/foo.Common/project.json
./src/foo.bar.MongoDB/project.json
./src/foo.bar/project.json
./src/foo.bar.Queries/project.json
./src/foo.Graph/project.json
./src/foo-http-frontend/project.json
./src/foo.Http.Model/project.json
./src/foo.Infrastructure/project.json
./src/foo.Search/project.json
```

What I also want to do is to list the project.json files under `./workers/*/` path but I am not sure how to combine it. My end goal is to be able concatinate two file globbings together, something like:

```
projectDirectories=./src/*/,./workers/*/
projectJsonFiles=${projectDirectories%%/}/project.json
for projectFilePath in $projectJsonFiles; do echo $projectFilePath; done
```

which would give me:

```
./src/foo-aspnet-configuration/project.json
./src/foo.Common/project.json
./src/foo.bar.MongoDB/project.json
./src/foo.bar/project.json
./src/foo.bar.Queries/project.json
./src/foo.Graph/project.json
./src/foo-http-frontend/project.json
./src/foo.Http.Model/project.json
./src/foo.Infrastructure/project.json
./src/foo.Search/project.json
./workers/foo.Sync.Common/project.json
./workers/foo-sync-foobar/project.json
./workers/foo-sync-bar/project.json
```

but obviously, `projectDirectories=./src/*/,./workers/*/` doesn't work. Any idea how this is done in bash?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU bash 4:

```
printf -v projectDirectories "%s" ./src/*/ ./workers/*/
echo "$projectDirectories"
```

Comment: thanks! I think it should be `printf -v projectDirectories "%s " ./src/*/ ./workers/*/` for it to work in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array rather than depend on filepaths not including whitespace:

```
dirs=(./src/*/ ./workers/*/)
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  file=${dir}project.json; do
    echo "$file"
  done
done
```